# Wireless Broadcom adapter is not working in Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 4.2

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, broadcom

I updated kernel to 4.2 in Ubuntu 14.04 by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

My wifi is not working but my ethernet is working. Please help me out.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2230]
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I have edited my question @Pilot6

Comment: Do you ever update your system?

Comment: For wireless troubleshooting please run the command suggested in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/205638), put the output in pastebin.com or paste.ubuntu.com, and link the paste in your question.

Comment: It is not needed any more.

Comment: Sure, it worked for me already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Broadcom driver was not updated for kernel 4.2, or you never updated your system. Anyway you can install it this way:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb
```